# how to list all uncommitted changes made only in current branch in git

Tags: git, branch, git-commit, git-checkout

I am a newbie to git initially i used to work only on master branch then i read a little about git branching and i was amazed by it power so i started using branches in my workflow

when i started with branching my master branch was clean nothing to commit.
Then I created new branch **feature1**

```
git checkout -b feature1
```

i made my changes in branch **feature1** added some js and css files . Then i created another branch from master branch without committing changes made to branch **feature1** like so :

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature2
```

i added some more code in **feature2** branch and added some new css files and then again i created another branch **feature3** from master with committing changes in branch **feature2** like this :

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b feature 3
```

I added some new code in **feature3** branch with 1 new css file . now when i did :

```
git status
```

I got list of all files which i modified but not committed in all the 3 branches . I was expecting that i will get only list of file modified in current branch i.e branch **feature3** , now i don't remember which files I created in which branch .

Can anyone please help me to list only files i created or modified in particular branch and commit them. to respective branches .

For e.g

list all files modified or created in **feature1** branch and commit them to **feature1** branch and do this with all 3 branches.

I also want to know how i can create a branch from master branch without getting other files which are modified in other branch but not committed . i.e i want the new branch to be exact clone of master with noting to commit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned by @abeaumet if you create files but don't commit them, you can't track them when you change branches.

This is because they are in your working tree and not your git repository. Your working tree  is effectively a checked out version of your repository, plus any changes you're currently making. Moving around branches does not delete these untracked files, git is leaving them in your working tree so they don't get deleted.

Read some of the articles linked in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/difference-between-head-working-tree-index-in-git) to understand the difference between your repository and the working tree.

Answer (score 8):

Just launch `gitk --all` and you can inspect all your branches, changes, whatever. Select a point and right-click on another and from top of the menu you get diff of two versions.

A branch in git is just a 'label' on a commit. If you create a branch on top of the master, it is as perfect "clone" as you can get. Though really it's just a 41 byte file containing the same hash.

I think you should familiraize yourself a bit with what is what, from the description I could not deduce what you did and especially what you're after.

Comment: i had a clean master branch i created new branch f1 added some code but i didn't commit the new changes added to f1 bcoz i didn't wanted to mess commit history ,then i created another branch f2 from master here too i added new code but didn't commit them ,again i created new branch f3 and added some new code to f3 so i wanted to commit changes made to f3 so i checked git status now here its listing all files i have modified in f1,f2,f3 so now i want to know which where the only file i created in f3 so i that i can commit them . So how can i list only file i added in f3 branch or any otr branch

Comment: that does not sound any good. the "new" branches you created are practically all equivalent and point to same place. And all your local changes are together, without any info on your intent. Rule of thumb: commit (or stash) before doing anything, especially change branch. "Clutter" is no problem if you don't push, it is all local and can be redone in may ways if you don't like it.

Comment: ok great lesson learned commit before making any new branch tat was really helpful

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible to determine on which branch a file was created if you didn't commit it.