# Need a little help understanding what Git does with branches

Tags: git

I've been using Git for a few months now. I finally have the hang of committing changes and pushing changes to remotes, but I'm not clear on what happens to a file in a branch. They do not work the way I expect.

Let's say I have file `index.html`. If I perform the following steps, I would expect to have a completely blank `index.html` file, but that's not the case.

1. Working in `master` branch
2. Create new branch `test`
3. Checkout `test`
4. Open `index.html`
5. Add "test" to file
6. Close file
7. Checkout `master` branch again
8. Delete branch `test`

If I open `index.html`, that `test` is still in my file. I expect that, as I never committed the changes to the file, nor merged the `test` branch into the `master` branch, my `index.html` file should revert back to how it was before I created the `test` branch.

I must be thinking of this wrong. Can someone enlighten me?

Answer (score 2):

The behavior of git when switching branches is to leave modified files unchanged.  This makes it easy to switch to a branch and commit the changes to the target branch.  From the docs

> Local modifications to the files in the working tree are kept, so that they can be committed to the . ([Link](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html))

If you want to get your working area onto the current state of master then you can do the following after checking out master

```
git reset --hard
```

Comment: thanks. so if i wanted to create a new branch to modify a file, test it and then decide I basically wanted to "undo" everything I did in that branch, I'm using git reset --hard? If so, am I thinking of branches incorrectly or is my work flow suspect?

Comment: @Bardo_J i don't want to say you're thinking of branches incorrectly.  It's more likely that git is just different that the most other SCC systems you've used before.  It requires a different way of thinking.  Took me prob 3 months to get in the right mindset myself.

Comment: @Bardo_J if you want to undo changes then `git reset` is the command to go to, if you want to change the branch you are commiting to then `git checkout`.  But in many ways you can use both commands to achieve very similar ends

Comment: OK! I think figured out why it's not working as I expected.

If I create a branch, make a change and don't commit it, my files behave as I've described in my original question.

If I stage and commit those changes in a new branch, check out the master branch and then delete the feature branch without merging the changes, my files return to their pre-feature branch state. 

Hopefully this helps someone in the future.

Answer (score 1):

"index.html" will be reverted if you reset local changes with `git reset --hard MASTER` or with `git checkout --force`. These operations actually modifies working tree.

Otherwise changes in the working tree will be left.

Take a look at this question to get into terms like "HEAD", "working tree" and so on: [Difference between HEAD / Working Tree / Index in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/difference-between-head-working-tree-index-in-git)

Comment: Thanks! So what is the point of a branch, then? My understanding was that you could create a branch, make modifications which don't apply to your MASTER branch until you merge them in?

Comment: Point of branch is nice-to-read-and-remember reference to a specific commit. Maybe in your flow you have forget to do `git commit` to save settings in the modified file? And you're understanding it correctly, this commit will be only in `test` branch and not in `master`.