# git reset vs git reset HEAD

Tags: git, git-reset, unstage

Every time a file has been staged, Git offers helpful instructions in the event you needed to unstage a file:

`(use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)`

However the decent [Git Tutorials by Atlassian](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/undoing-changes/git-reset) simply say:

`git reset <file>`

This seems more straightforward, so why the difference?

Comment: Note: you also have now `git restore --staged -- afile`, with Git 2.23 (August 2019). See [my edited answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33849726/6309)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No difference (from [`git reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset)) in term of default parameter:

> The `<tree-ish>/<commit>` defaults to `HEAD` in all forms.

That message initially did *not* include HEAD: [commit 3c1eb9c, Jan. 2007, git 1.5.0-rc1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3c1eb9cb2d57769f770ddc36fd6b49706608ebb7), but since the default is *not* always known, the help message makes it clear to which commit you are supposed to reset.

`HEAD` appears in [commit 367c988, Nov. 2007, Git 1.5.4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/367c98866c340bc9cf5cfa88c3b69f027165fc44):

```
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
```

---

[torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) points out an actual difference [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849704/git-reset-vs-git-reset-head/33849726#comment55470127_33849726):

> By  specifying `HEAD`, you guarantee that the first word after `HEAD` is taken as a path name.
> For instance, suppose you run `git reset zorg`. Is `zorg` a tree-ish, such as a tag name, or is it a path name, `./zorg`?
> Git's answer is: it's a tree-ish if [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) can turn it into a tree ID, otherwise it's a path.
> You can either write `git reset -- zorg` or `git reset HEAD zorg` to make sure that git treats it as a path.

See more on the double hyphen syntax ( `--` ) in "[Deleting a badly named git branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1192194/6309)".

---

---

---

The [OP skube](https://stackoverflow.com/users/572747/skube) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849704/git-reset-vs-git-reset-head/33849726?noredirect=1#comment55559254_33849726):

> As an aside, they do suggest it for discarding changes in working directory
> (i.e `git checkout -- <file>`).
> It just seems inconsistent with `git reset HEAD <file>`.

While [`git reset` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-reset) clearly indicates the lack of tree-ish in `git reset <tree-ish> -- <paths>` means HEAD, it is not so for [`git checkout <tree-ish> -- <paths>`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -- <pathspec>
```

> When `<paths>` are given, `git checkout` does not switch branches.
> **It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file** or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).

That means `git checkout -- path` will override the working tree with what has already been staged (`git add`'ed).
While `git reset -- PATH` (being the mixed form of git reset) will reset *the index* with what HEAD contains (effectively un-staging what was added)

`git reset` and `git checkout` don't use the same default, and:

- you can represent the default tree for `git reset <tree-ish> <file>`: `HEAD`.
  Hence `git reset HEAD <file>`;
- but you cannot represent the default parameter when you don't provide a tree for `git checkout`: it is the index.
  Hence `git checkout -- file`.

The `--` has to be used in the `git checkout` case, since there is only one parameter, and it needs to be clear that parameter represents *files*.

Note that `git checkout HEAD files` is different: [torek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1256452/torek) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33849704/git-reset-vs-git-reset-head/33849726?noredirect=1#comment55559254_33849726)

> `git checkout HEAD path` copies from the `HEAD` commit (the tree-ish) to the index and then on to the working dir.

---

Note: with Git 2.23+, August 2019, you might use **[`git restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309)** instead

See [the examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#_examples):

> To restore a file in the index to match the version in HEAD (this is the same as using `git-reset`)
>
> ```
> $ git restore --staged hello.c
> ```

man page:

`git restore --staged hello.c` does not specify a source, and restore the index only ([`--staged`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore#Documentation/git-restore.txt--W)): it does so (by default) using HEAD as source.

> By default, the restore *sources* for working tree and the index are the index and HEAD respectively.
> `--source` could be used to specify a commit as the restore source.

Other examples:

> You can restore both the index and the working tree (this the same as using `git-checkout`)
>
> ```
> $ git restore --source=HEAD --staged --worktree hello.c
> ```
>
> or the short form which is more practical but less readable:
>
> ```
> $ git restore -s@ -SW hello.c
> ```

`git restore` is a more natural command name, and has no ambiguity.

Comment: It's worth adding that by specifying `HEAD` you guarantee that the first word after `HEAD` is taken as a path name.  For instance, suppose you run `git reset zorg`.  Is `zorg` a tree-ish, such as a tag name, or is it a path name, `./zorg`?  Git's answer is: it's a tree-ish if `git rev-parse` can turn it into a tree ID, otherwise it's a path.  You can either write `git reset -- zorg` or `git reset HEAD zorg` to make sure that git treats it as a path.

Comment: @torek Very true, as usual. I have included your comment in the answer (with additional links) for more visibility.

Comment: So if `git reset -- <file>` and `git reset HEAD <file>` are functionally the same, and both being a little safer than simply `git reset <file>`, why does git offer the suggestion to use the `HEAD` version? Surely, it easier to type `--` than `HEAD`. As an aside, they do suggest it for discarding changes in working directory (i.e `git checkout -- <file>`). It just seems inconsistent.

Comment: @skube because Git wants you to be aware that the syntax invoves a `<treeish>` *before* the file. `git reset -- <file>` obfuscates that entirely.

Comment: @torek the OP points out an interesting inconsistency between two help message: `git reset HEAD <file>` and `git checkout -- <file>`: why the different syntax?

Comment: With `git checkout`, the `--` version (`git checkout -- path`) tells git to copy out of the index (extract index version to work dir), while `git checkout HEAD path` copies from the `HEAD` commit to the index and then on to the work dir.  I find this particular difference especially confusing, but since `git reset` is resetting the index, it does actually make sense.

Comment: @torek: so while `git reset -- <file>` and `git reset HEAD <file>` are identical, `git checkout -- <file>` and `git checkout HEAD <file>` are not? In other word, the absence of treeish in  `git checkout -- <file>` does not mean by default `HEAD` (while it does default to `HEAD` for `git reset`)

Comment: @torek After re-reading the doc, it makes sense now. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: @skube Thanks to torek, I have edited the answer to address the apparent inconsistency between `git reset HEAD <file>` and `git checkout -- file`.

Answer (score 4):

By default, `git reset` is equivalent to `git reset HEAD`

Quoting the man page (my emphasis):

> git-reset - Reset current HEAD to the specified state.
>
> ```
> git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…
> git reset (--patch | -p) [<tree-ish>] [--] [<paths>…​]
> git reset [--soft | --mixed [-N] | --hard | --merge | --keep] [-q] [<commit>]
> ```
>
> In the first and second form, copy entries from <tree-ish> to the index. In the third form, set the current branch head (HEAD) to <commit>, optionally
>   modifying index and working tree to match. **The <tree-ish>/<commit>
>   defaults to HEAD in all forms.**
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> git reset [-q] [<tree-ish>] [--] <paths>…​
> ```
>
> This form resets the index entries for all <paths> to their state at <tree-ish>. (It does not affect the working tree or the current
>   branch.)
>
> **This means that `git reset <paths>` is the opposite of `git add <paths>`.**

From this you see that there's no actual difference in behavior.

> This seems more straightforward, so why the difference?

Since they're both the same, you might as well use the shortest version of the two.

Answer (score 1):

First time, before any commit the HEAD does not exist, then we get:

```
$git reset HEAD stagedFile
fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree
```