# Git: Undo modified files before adding to stage

Tags: git

How to undo a modified file on Git? If I do a `git status` I get the message: `modified: project/index.html` however I want to undo all changes on that file before adding to stage.

Comment: The `git status` output message already tells you how to do it:

`Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)`

Comment: If you undo the changes then there will be nothing to stage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do git checkout of that file

```
git checkout project/index.html
```

Comment: To see more about that `git checkout -- file`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33849726/6309.