# What's the difference between overwriting a file and checking it out?

Tags: git

My git repository got into a strange state today. A file was reported by `git status` as modified, but `git diff` showed no changes. After a searching on internet, I checked the file attributes (read/write/execute and owner GID/UID) and content (in case it was a line endings issue). The attributes were correctly set, and `md5sum theFile` and `git show HEAD:theFile | md5sum` reported the same hash.

I then tried to overwrite the working tree file with the one stored in git: `git show HEAD:theFile > theFile`. Surprisingly, `git status` continued to report changes on this file.

Then, I checked out the file: `git checkout -- theFile`, and after that, `git status` changed its opinion and reported no changes on `theFile`.

I can't understand the difference between `show HEAD:theFile > theFile` and `checkout -- theFile`. Maybe git is keeping information in cache, which is updated by `checkout` but not by `show ... >` ?

Comment: Maybe it could also be whitespaces added/removed.

Comment: It could be white spaces. However, here, as md5 sums are similar, I'm pretty sure that's not the case.

Answer (score 1):

[As I detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33849726/6309):

```
git checkout <tree-ish> -- <pathspec>
```

> When `<paths>` are given, git checkout does not switch branches.
>   It updates the named paths in the working tree from the index file or from a named `<tree-ish>` (most often a commit).
>
> That means `git checkout -- path` will **override the working tree with what has already been staged** (git add'ed).

`git checkout -- theFile` makes the index and working tree identical, which means `git diff` is empty.

`show HEAD:theFile > theFile` does not modify the index, so a git diff would still report differences between the index and the working tree.

Comment: Thanks. This explain the difference between `checkout -- theFile` and `show HEAD:theFile > theFile`. However, if no modification is staged on this file (there are nothing in the index concerning it), I expect that making the working tree identical to the index or to `HEAD` produces a similar result, isn't it ?

Comment: @ryolait maybe there is a .gitattributes which concerns that file?

Comment: No. `find <whole git repo> -name .gitattributes` returns nothing, and `.git/info/attributes` does not exists.