# difference between `git checkout HEAD -- fileA.cpp` vs `git checkout -- fileA.cpp`

Tags: git

Based on [Meaning of Git checkout double dashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13321458/meaning-of-git-checkout-double-dashes)

```
git checkout -- fileA.cpp
```

I want to revert changes on `fileA.cpp`.

Question> Is there a different between the `checkout` with or without `HEAD`?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a difference, which matters if and only if the version of `fileA.cpp` in the index differs from the version of `fileA.cpp` in the `HEAD` commit.

Specifically, without the word `HEAD`, `git checkout -- <path>` extracts the version of `<path>` from the index to the work-tree, leaving the index version unchanged.  Adding `HEAD` before the `--`, `git checkout HEAD -- <path>` extracts the version of `<path>` from the commit identified by `HEAD`, writes *that* into the index, and only then writes the index version (now the same as the `HEAD` version) into the work-tree.

See also [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33849726/1256452) (on `git reset` initially, but extended to cover checkout as well).

Comment: I did some experiments. It seems to me that `git checkout -- <path>' causes no changes if `working copy` is equal to `index`. So I think it is always true that we can use `get checkout HEAD -- path` if you want to get the latest copy from last committed checkin.