# difference between git checkout file and git checkout -- file

Tags: git

I'm learning git and in the [git-checkout](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) documentation points that if you delete a file (from the explorer not from git directly) then you can recover by calling `git checkout -- file`, but I tried without the double dash as `git checkout file` and the result is exactly the same apparentrly... in this context, what it means `--`?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean-also-known-as-bare-double-dash

Comment: The answer is the same as in this one about `git reset`, as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33849726/1256452