# fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git in Mac OS

Tags: github, arduino

I tried a lot to compile my ArduPilot(got this code from GitHub) code using different method.

1. using Eclipse
2. command line

This code is written in C++ language.

I just want to create a make file to get `.hex` file but everywhere I have got same problem

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I am doing work in Mac OS so how can I avoid that error message?

Comment: Please provide some code (e.g. the command line method) or links to your github repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be sure: if you create a file, you should not create *in* the `.git/` folder itself, but in its parent folder:

```
myrepo
  yourfile <===
  .git/
```

The `.git/` folder include git data/metadata representing your git repo.
The parent folder is [the working tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/6309) of the repo.

If you don't have a `.git/` folder in "`myrepo`", type `git init .`

Comment: but now im facing some another problem.                                                 cc1plus: error: unrecognized command line option "-std=gnu++11"

Comment: @DolatSingh OK. Can you ask a separate question for that, with the exact version of git, the version of your OS (Windows, Mac, Linux; ...) and more detail about the command you type which result in that error message?