# Plesk automatically update submodule on git repository change

Tags: git, git-submodules, plesk

I have setup my plesk website to automatically pull changes from a remote repository to a certain path of the webserver via post-hooks as described [here](https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/customer-guide/git-support/using-remote-git-hosting.75848/#o76297).

However my repository contains a git submodule and I need to run the custom command `git submodule update --remote` as well. How can I tell plesk to do that. The commands I can enter in the

> Enable Additional Deployment Actions

Setting seem not to be executed in the correct path. Also when I go to the path the repository syncs to on my server i get:

`fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git`

How can I achive to tell plesk to update submodules too with the git plugin?

Comment: Seems that the same question has been asked here: https://talk.plesk.com/threads/git-deployment-with-submodules-and-error-handling.340329/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In my case it was two problems. It was a setting for a subdomain, where the folderstructure is different in plesk.

First I had to set the "Additional Deployment Action" to

```
# find the correct git folders / repositorys by ssh-ing onto your server
git --git-dir=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/git/example.git --work-tree=/var/www/vhosts/example.com/subdomain.example.com/path/to/working-directory/ submodule update --init --recursive
```

The second problem was that the submodule was placed on github, so I had to add the specific subdomain ssh-key to github. It can be found in.

```
/var/www/vhosts/example.com/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

even for the subdomain. Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: So setting git-dir/git_work-tree was part of the solution. +1

Comment: For background these are 2 different directories since Plesk uses a bare repository for git in $HOME/git/{site} which is separate to where the files are cloned to (usually $HOME/{site} for subdomains

Answer (score 2):

Check if you are in the right folder ([as I show here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36676003/6309))

Then check your environment variables ([seen here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18947812/6309)): `GIT_DIR` or `GIT_WORK_TREE`, as set by Plex, to make sure they are not interfering.

Answer (score 0):

For me Niklas answer did not work unless I did a cd into the worktree directory. You can add this to the git command itself (using `-C`). Also I have added a sync command, in case the submodules origin changes:

```
git --git-dir=/git/repo_name.git --work-tree=. -C /httpdocs/website submodule sync --recursive
git --git-dir=/git/repo_name.git --work-tree=. -C /httpdocs/website submodule update --init --recursive
```

I want to also note, that using variables did not work for me, I had to use absolute path for both commands.

Note: My hoster is netcup.com, maybe that is a specific issue on their side, but I guess it is relevant for all plesk installations.

Comment: Strange: `-C` (that I [documented here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20115526/6309) in 2013 with Git 1.8.5) is precisely a shortcut to set `--git-dir` and `--work-tree`. I don't know how that would help in your case.

Comment: If I dont use `-C` I get the following error: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48767595/14348748

Answer (score 0):

Although it's been a while here my two cents.
I'm glad the given answers where pointing me in the right direction, however I still had to struggle with this quite some time.

Here is my summary:

#### Using submodules in Plesk

- repos to be integrated as submodules *must not* be privat
- Don't `ssh` ! To integrate an external repo we must use `https` protocol:  `git submodule add https://github.com/example.repo.git` - see https://github.com/docker-library/golang/issues/148
- the ${HOME} user (see code below) is used to authorize against github, so *his* key pair needs to be generated and the public key must be stored at Github
- `ssh` into your account using the `${HOME}` users name and password. In Plesk the `${HOME}` user is the owner of the subscription `domain.com` or `sub.domain.com` belongs to.
- to generate a key pair do:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

- key pairs are automatically stored under the users home directory: `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa` and `${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
- copy the generated *public* key over to Github

#### Usage

(under "*Additional deployment actions*")

```c
git --git-dir=${HOME}/git/example.repo.git --work-tree=. submodule update --init &> ~/logs/git/example.repo.log
git --git-dir=${HOME}/git/example.repo.git --work-tree=. checkout master &>> ~/logs/git/example.repo.log
git --git-dir=${HOME}/git/example.repo.git --work-tree=. pull origin master &>> ~/logs/git/example.repo.log
git --git-dir=${HOME}/git/example.repo.git --work-tree=. submodule update --init --recursive &>> ~/logs/git/example.repo.log

git commit -am "submodule updated $(date)"
```

or the short way

```c
git --git-dir=${HOME}/git/example.repo.git --work-tree=. submodule foreach 'git submodule update --init;git checkout master;git pull origin master;git submodule update --init --recursive;' &> ~/logs/git/example.repo.log

git commit -am "submodule updated $(date)"
```

Explanation: we must use `--git-dir` and `--work-tree` here because of Plesks folder structure. Normally `.git` files are located within the main repository folder. Here these files are in its own `git` folder:

```
 -- domain.com
    -- git
       -- example.repo.git
    -- sub.domain.com
```