# What does "Keep Index" option of Git stash dialog in Intellij IDEA do?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

It is said in [IDEA documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/stash-dialog.html)

> Select this check box to have IntelliJ IDEA bring the changes staged in the index to your working tree for examination and testing.

Can somebody please explain what does this mean?

Comment: `--keep-index` keeps  staged changes and stashes un-tracked changes.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This determines if the stash is created with the git `--keep-index` flag.

From [GIT docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash#_options):

> If the `--keep-index` option is used, all changes already added to the index are left intact.

So in other words, any files you've added to git will also remain outside of the stash when you create it. Whereas normally newly added files would be removed after stashing. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/difference-between-head-working-tree-index-in-git) for a more indepth description of where the index is.)

Comment: thus in the end your staged changes remain in your workspace *and* are saved into your stash

Comment: this is a good answer to review as well: "Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch" : https://stackoverflow.com/a/22055552/401226