# git diff <fileName> showing changes for new branch and old branch

Tags: git, github

I had committed code changes of test.js in one branch(old). Now I have created new branch and did some code changes in same test.js file. While doing

```
git diff test.js
```

showing code changes of old branch changes and new code changes.

Is it shows all code changes(changes that I have committed in old branhc and new changes)?

Answer (score 3):

In general, `git diff` compares just two things.  (The exceptions do not apply here.)  You pick *which* two things, and Git gives you a set of instructions, e.g.:

- take out this line at this location
- put in this other line at this other location

that will, if you follow them, transform the *first* thing into the *second* thing.

In this particular case, the two things you selected with:

```
git diff test.js
```

are the version of `test.js` that is in the *index*, and the version of `test.js` that is in the *work-tree*.  Neither of these is necessarily in *any* branch (though, of course, either or both versions could match some version(s) of some file(s) in some other branch(es)).

The short description of the work-tree is simple enough: it's where you work on your files.  Files stored inside Git are in a Git-only format, so for the other programs on your computer to use them, you need to have them in a place you can work on them.  That's the work-tree.

The short description of the index is that it is where you have Git build up your *next* commit.  It starts out matching your *current* commit, from your current branch; when you `git add` a file, that copies the file from the work-tree into the index, so that it's ready to go into the *next* commit.

To read more about what Git's *index* and *work-tree* are and do, see [Difference between HEAD / Working Tree / Index in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3689838/1256452).

Answer (score 0):

`git diff test.js` will show changes in the file in **only** current branch.