# Trouble understanding git submodule summary

Tags: git, git-submodules

I am facing some problems in understanding what *exactly* does `git submodule summary` do? How and when do we use this command? I am also not able to understand the significance of the `--files` option. To me, not using the tag seems the same as using it.

Also, how will it differ from `git submodule status`? I am extremely confused. I had been reading the [Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#_name) of the command if it helps.

Thank you so much in advance for the help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `git submodule status`:

```
$ git submodule status
hash-1 path-1 (describe-output-1)
hash-2 path-2 (describe-output-2)
   :
hash-n path-n (describe-output-n)
```

This tells you, for each submodule path, the hash ID of the commit that is checked out within that submodule path, and the result of running `git describe` within that submodule.  For instance, if you saw

```
 51ebf55b9309824346a6589c9f3b130c6f371b8f foo (v2.25.0-462-g51ebf55b93)
```

as the output, but then did a `git checkout v2.15.0` in the `foo` directory:

```
(cd foo; git checkout v2.15.0)
```

and ran it again, you'd see:

```
+cb5918aa0d50f50e83787f65c2ddc3dcb10159fe foo (v2.15.0)
```

instead.  (The `+` sign indicates that it's out of sync; see below.)

The hash ID is simply the result of running `git rev-parse HEAD` in each submodule.  The describe output is simply the result of running `git describe` in each submodule.  The path in the middle is the argument you'd need to supply to a `cd` (change-directory) command to switch from the superproject into the given submodule.

For `git submodule summary`, the details are a little more complicated.  This basically runs a `git log` in each submodule, though.

#### Basics of submodules

Remember that a submodule is nothing more or less than another Git repository—the one that Git calls the *submodule*—plus a little bit of glue in *this* Git repository, which Git calls the *superproject*.  The "glue" in the superproject consists of a very small number of items:

- Information needed to `git clone` the submodule, stored in a file named `.gitmodules`.  This only gets used when you first tell the superproject Git to do that clone, e.g., via `git submodule update --init`.
- The *path name* of the submodule, as it appears in the superproject.  The superproject Git will make an empty directory / folder (whichever term you prefer) to hold the work-tree for this submodule.<sup>1</sup>
- A *commit hash ID*.  The superproject Git will take this commit hash ID, and in effect, run `(cd path; git checkout hash)` to put the submodule Git into *detached HEAD* mode, with that particular commit checked out.

These last two items are stored in every new commit you make in the superproject (and are already stored in existing commits).<sup>2</sup>  In order to *get* stored, the path name and commit hash ID must be stored in Git's *index*, because Git makes all new commits from the index.

(If you're not clear on the distinction between Git's *index* and your *work-tree*, see [What's the difference between HEAD, working tree and index, in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3689838/1256452) and [What does git-rm mean by working tree and index?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43095440/1256452).)

---

<sup>1</sup>In modern Git, the `.git` for the submodule that will appear within this path is an ordinary file whose contents will be a path under which the submodule Git can find the repository.  The superproject Git will move the repository database out of the submodule.  Git calls this *absorbing* the submodule.  In older versions of Git, the submodule will have its own `.git` directory/folder that contains the submodule Git repository database.

<sup>2</sup>In fact, the first item—the `.gitmodules` file—should also be in all these commits, but since it's an ordinary file, there is nothing special about it: you just work with it like you do any ordinary file.  Since the superproject only really *needs* it once, when cloning the submodule, if you accidentally or on purpose leave it out of new commits, you won't notice until someone else tries to use that commit as a starting point for a fresh clone of the superproject.

Since it's quite rare to *change* a `.gitmodules` file, and it carries across commits otherwise just like any other file, this is rarely a problem.  It's mostly a problem only if you create the submodule using something other than `git submodule add` in the first place.

---

#### Reading gitlinks, vs messing with the submodule directly

The superproject entity that records both the path and hash ID, ready to go into your next commit, is called a *gitlink*.  It exists only in Git's index, so it is very hard to see.  (You can dump out the index contents using `git ls-files --stage`, but this is usually way too verbose.)  But it's always there: it says *to use **this** commit, check out, as a detached HEAD, **this** hash ID in **this** submodule*.

Let's suppose that there's a submodule at the path `sub` (in the index, as `:sub` or `:0:sub`—the number here is the staging slot).  When you make commits in the superproject, this gitlink goes into commits.  You can read it out of the index:

```
git rev-parse :sub
```

or read it out of the current commit:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:sub
```

or read it out of any commit:

```
git rev-parse <hash>:sub
```

to get the stored gitlink hash ID for `sub` from the given commit hash-ID.

If you run `git submodule update` in your superproject, that Git will do the appropriate `(cd sub; git checkout <hash>)` based on whatever hash ID is in the index right now.  That `git checkout` will, if the submodule repository is "clean", cleanly check out that particular commit.

But each submodule *is* a Git repository—a work-tree, an index, and an underlying repository-database.  *You* can `cd sub` and `git checkout` whatever you want, or dirty up *its* (`sub`'s) index and/or its work-tree.  And, that submodule can have its own branch names—it's a Git repository, and every Git repository has branch names, right?  Suppose you `cd sub; git checkout master` for instance.  Now that submodule is *on a branch*, not in *detached HEAD* mode.  You can make new commits, run `git merge`, and/or run all kinds of other commands.  You can fetch new commits from some upstream repository.  You can do anything you want: it's a Git repository, with all Git commands available.

Suppose, then, that you've done something—it doesn't really matter what—to some Git repository that's acting as a submodule for some superproject.  Now you return to the superproject (`cd ..`), and *in* the superproject, you ask it: *which commit did you recommend be checked out?*  That is, you read the *gitlink* entry in the superproject, from the superproject's index, or from a commit.

You have two hash IDs.  They may be the same!  Maybe `master` in the submodule *is* the hash ID stored in the superproject's gitlink.  Or, maybe they're different.  If you made a new commit just now in the submodule, they're definitely different, because every new commit hash ID is unique.

If the two are different, `git submodule status` will print `+<hash>`; the hash it prints is the one that's actually checked out in `sub`.  If the two are the same, it prints the (single) hash ID without the `+`.

Meanwhile, if you run `git submodule summary`, your superproject Git:

- grabs the *recommended* hash ID
- grabs the *actually checked out* hash ID
- uses `git log` in the submodule to find which commits are "between" these two hash IDs.

Specifically, it uses `git log --oneline --left-right <hash1>...<hash2>` (note the `--oneline` and the three dots here; it also forces a few more options but these are the key ones).  The *`hash1`* value is the *recommended* hash and the *`hash2`* value is the *actually checked out* hash.  The result of this listing is to show commits that are reachable from *`hash1`* but not *`hash2`* (prefixed with `<`) and commits that are reachable from *`hash2`* but not *`hash1`* (prefixed with `>`).

(For much more about *reachability*, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).)

#### `git submodule summary`: `--files` vs `--cached`

> I am also not able to understand the significance of the `--files` option

The `--files` option is the default.  The `--cached` option changes where `git submodule summary` gets its two hash IDs.  Instead of getting the first hash from the index (`:sub`), and then going into the submodule and reading out the `HEAD` value for the second, it reads the first ID from the *current commit* (`HEAD:sub`) and gets the *second* from the index (`:sub`).  The remainder of its operation is the same: enter the submodule and run `git log` with appropriate options.

Comment: That was a GREAT explanation!!
though I have one doubt, can we say that `--cached` is the exact opposite of `--files`? By opposite, I mean that the way they fetch the two hashIDs.

Comment: Given that `--files` picks up two hash IDs (extracted from index in superproject, and value-of-HEAD in submodule) and `--cached` picks up two hash IDs (extracted from a commit in superproject and extracted from index in superproject), I would not call them *opposites*. One of the two hashes is from the same source but in the opposite position; the other of the two hashes is from a different source. That's neither just a transposition, nor a complete difference.