# What is the difference between "git checkout -- ." and "git reset HEAD --hard"?

Tags: git, git-checkout, git-reset, git-clean

This is not a general question about what '--' does, as in the marked duplicate. This is a git-specific question asking for clarity on what the operational differences are between the mentioned commands.

If I want to clean out my current directory without stashing or committing, I usually use these commands:

```
git reset HEAD --hard
git clean -fd
```

A co-worker also mentioned using this command:

```
git checkout -- .
```

It's a difficult command to google, and it's not clear to me from the git documentation what this command actually does. It seems to be one of the later-mentioned usages in the manual.

At a guess it replicates `git reset HEAD --hard`, but what exactly does it do as compared to the commands I'm already using?
Does it replicate one or both of the commands, or is it similar yet subtly different?

Comment: There are a bunch of questions about this across Stack Overflow and other SE sites: https://www.google.ca/search?q=bash+what+does+double+dash+do&oq=bash+what+does+double+dash+do&aqs=chrome..69i57.3761j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: git checkout -- filename will undo any unstaged changes for a particular file. 

git checkout -- . will do the same thing for all files in the current folder.

Comment: @meagar thanks, it's not so much a question of what a double dash does in general as how this works with git. I think it's a common enough usage of a commonly used tool to warrant a git-specific answer.

Comment: @Tim510 Is that to say that this command will only work with files that exist, and does not use the git index, in which case the command is *not* the same as either of the others I'm using?

Comment: Git generally treats `--` in the POSIX-approved manner, as an end-of-options marker, so that `git whatever -a -- -b -c` treats only `-a` as an *option* and `-b` and `-c` as *non-option arguments*. The `--` in `git checkout --` just means that whatever follows the `--` it is treated as a *path name* even if it resembles an option (`-f` means the file `-f`, not `--force`) or a branch name (`master` means the file `master`, not the branch `master`). As for `git checkout .` (with or without the `--`), this is the file-extraction form and it *is* slightly (subtly) different from `git reset --HARD`.

Comment: Specifically, `git reset --hard` will *remove* from the index any entries that do not have a corresponding file in the commit while *replacing* existing entries with those from the commit, while `git checkout -- .` will *replace* existing entries with those from the commit, but not *remove* any. Also `.` means the *current* directory which may or may not be the *top level* directory, depending on where you are in the repository tree.

Comment: @torek: Thanks, that's the sort of answer I was after - an explanation of the subtle differences between the commands. If you want to write it as an answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @M_M: working on it now. There are more details than I got into in the comments, because Git's model here is quite complicated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

First, let's just address the double hyphen or double dash, to get it out of the way (especially since this question no longer has a marked duplicate).

Git mostly uses this in [the POSIX-approved fashion (see Guideline 10)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap12.html), to indicate a dividing line between option arguments and non-option arguments.  Since `git checkout` accepts branch names, as in `git checkout master`, and also file (path) names, as in `git checkout README.txt`, you can use the `--` to force Git to interpret whatever comes after the `--` as a file name, even if it would otherwise be a valid branch name.  That is, if you have both a *branch* and a *file* named `master`:

```
git checkout master
```

will check out the *branch*, but:

```
git checkout -- master
```

will check out the *file* (confusingly, from the current *index*).

#### [Branches, index, and files, oh my](http://ask.metafilter.com/15238/Where-does-the-phrase-X-Y-Z-Oh-my-come-from)

Next, we need to address a quirk of `git checkout`.  As one can see from [the documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html), there are many "modes" of `git checkout` (the documentation lists six separate invocations in the synposis!).  There are various rants (of varying quality: [Steve Bennet's](https://stevebennett.me/2012/02/24/10-things-i-hate-about-git/) is actually useful, in my opinion, though naturally I do not agree with it 100% :-) ) about Git's poor "user experience" model, including the fact that `git checkout` has too many modes of operation.

In particular, you can `git checkout` a *branch* (to switch branches), or `git checkout` one or more *files*.  The latter extracts the files from a particular commit, or from the index.  When Git extracts files from a commit, it first copies them *to* the index, and then copies them *from* the index, *to* the work-tree.

There is an underlying implementation reason for this sequence, but the fact that it shows through at all is a key element.  We need to know a lot about Git's index, because both `git checkout` and `git reset` use it, and sometimes in different ways.

It's a good idea, I think, to draw a three-way diagram or table illustrating the current—or `HEAD`—commit, the index, and the work-tree.  Suppose that:

- there are two ordinary, committed files `README.md` and `file.txt`;
- there is a new, `git add`-ed but uncommitted `new.txt`;
- there is a file named `rmd.txt` that has been `git rm`-ed but not committed;
- and there is an untracked file named `untr.txt`.

Each entity—the `HEAD` commit, the index, and the work-tree—holds three files right now, but each holds a *different set* of files.  The table of the entire state then looks like this:

```
  HEAD       index    work-tree
-------------------------------
README.md  README.md  README.md
file.txt   file.txt   file.txt
           new.txt    new.txt
rmd.txt
                      untr.txt
```

There are many more possible states than just these: in fact, for each file-name, there are *seven* possible combinations of "in/not-in" HEAD, index, and work-tree (the eighth combination is "not in all three", in which case, what file are we even talking about in the first place?!).

#### The `checkout` and `reset` commands

The two commands you're asking about, `git checkout` and `git reset`, are both able to do many things.  The specific invocations of each, however, reduce the "things done" to one of two, to which I will add several more:

- `git checkout -- .`: copies *from* index, *to* work-tree, only
- `git checkout HEAD -- .`: copies *from* HEAD, *to* index, and then *to* work-tree
- `git reset --mixed`: resets index from HEAD (and then leaves work-tree alone)
- `git reset --hard`: resets index from HEAD, then resets work-tree from index

These overlap a lot, but there are several crucially-different parts.

Let's consider the file named `new.txt` above in particular.  It's in the index right now, so if we copy *from* the index, *to* the work-tree, we replace the work-tree copy with the index copy.  This is what `git checkout -- new.txt` does, for instance.

If, instead, we start by copying from `HEAD` to the index, nothing happens to `new.txt` in the index: `new.txt` doesn't *exist* in `HEAD`.  Hence an explicit `git checkout HEAD -- new.txt` just fails, while a `git checkout HEAD -- .` copies the files that are in `HEAD` and leaves the two existing `new.txt` versions undisturbed.

The file `rmd.txt` is *gone* from the index, so if we `git checkout -- .`, Git does not see it and does nothing about it.  But if we `git checkout HEAD -- .`, Git copies `rmd.txt` from `HEAD` into the index (now it's back) and then from the index to the work-tree (and now it's back there, too).

The `git reset` command has a key difference when used with no path name arguments.  Here, it literally re-sets the index to match the commit.  That means that for `new.txt`, it notices that the file is not in `HEAD`, so it *removes* the index entry.  If used with `--hard`, it therefore also *removes* the work-tree entry.  Meanwhile `rmd.txt` *is* in `HEAD`, so it copies that back to the index, and with `--hard`, to the work-tree as well.

If there are unstaged, i.e., work-tree only, changes to the other two files `README.md` and `file.txt`, both forms of `git checkout` and the `--hard` form of `git reset` wipe out those changes.

If there are *staged* changes to those files—changes that have been copied into the index—then `git reset` un-stages them.  So does the variant of `git checkout` where you give it the name `HEAD`.  However, the variant of `git checkout` where you copy the index files back to the work-tree keeps those staged changes staged!

#### Top level vs current directory

Last, it's worth noting that `.`, meaning *the current directory*, may at any time be different from "top of Git repository":

```
$ git rev-parse --show-toplevel
/home/torek/src/kernel.org/git
$ pwd
/home/torek/src/kernel.org/git/Documentation
$ git rev-parse --show-cdup
../
```

Here, I am in the `Documentation` sub-directory of the top level directory `git`, so `.` means *everything in `Documentation` and its subdirectories*.  Using `git checkout -- .` will check out (from the index) all the `Documentation` and `Documentation/RelNotes` files, but not any of the `../builtin` files, for instance.  But `git reset`, when used without path names, will reset *all* entries, including those for `..` and `../builtin`.

Comment: `If there are staged changes to those files—changes that have been copied into the work-tree—` - should that be index instead of work-tree?