# Check for uncommitted changes in another branch x, without checking out branch x

Tags: git, git-diff, git-status

I want to determine if another branch has uncommitted changes, but I don't want to check that branch out. Basically I want to find out if another branch has a "dirty index". This means either staged or unstaged changes that are uncommitted.

Is this possible? From I have learned so far, I don't think you can use `git status` on any branch other than the one you have currently checked out. But what about `git diff`?

**Update**: I just realized that the only branch that can have a "dirty index" is your current branch, unless you use git-stash (I think). **So perhaps this question is better formulated as - how can I check if any branch has stashed/uncommitted changes?**

Comment: Are you asking whether your current local changes would appear as a diff relative to some *other* branch?

Comment: nah, I just want to find out if any local branch has a dirty index

Comment: Again, there's only the one index (per work-tree). To find out if it matches the current commit, and if the work-tree matches the index, from a script, use `require_clean_work_tree` from `git-sh-setup` in the `git --exec-path` directory (`. git-sh-setup; require_clean_work_tree`). Note that the --exec-path directory must be in `$PATH`, but if you name a script `git-foo` and then run `git foo`, that directory *will* be in `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: this took a while to write, and you updated your question in the meantime.  This answer is a lot longer than it might have needed to be.

---

> I want to determine if another branch [i.e., a branch other than the current branch] has uncommitted changes ...

The answer is that it doesn't.

In fact, *no* branch contains uncommitted changes.  It's literally impossible, and asking the question means that you're thinking that Git works in some other way than Git actually does work.

> Basically I want to find out if another branch has a "dirty index".

There is only one index.  Well, that's not *quite* true, but start with that!  Three is also only one *work-tree* (which is also not *quite* true, but again, let's start with that).

> ... [update] So perhaps this question is better formulated as - how can I check if any branch has stashed/uncommitted changes?

Here, you may wish to use the helper routines in `$(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup`.  View this file in your favorite editor, for instance.

#### How Git actually works

The way Git actually works is a little bit complicated.  The main body of any Git repository is a database that contains four types of Git objects, of which the most important for our purposes is the *commit*.  We can think of each Git repository as being composed of a series of commits.  Each commit has a unique hash ID—one of those big ugly hexadecimal numbers like `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`—that Git uses to extract the contents of the commit object.  The object itself is pretty small, but contains references to other hash IDs that eventually get you all the *files* in the snapshot of that commit.

Meanwhile, branch names like `master` simply hold hash IDs.  Each branch name holds *exactly one* hash ID.  So a name like `master` holds an ID like `b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f`.  Git calls this the *tip commit* of that branch.  The name-to-hash-ID mapping is a second database, sitting alongside the main hash-ID-to-object database.

The commit itself contains another hash ID—well, more than one, but let's take a look at this commit.  The `git cat-file -p` command pretty-prints the contents of an object.

```
$ git cat-file -p b7bd9486b055c3f967a870311e704e3bb0654e4f | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 1fd4a47af4942cbdee0bdcb4375612ab521a4a51
parent 5571d085b3c9c2aa9470a10bcf2b8518d3e4ec99
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700

Third batch for 2.19 cycle

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

The *tree* line gets us the snapshot for that commit.  The *parent* line tells us which commit comes *before* this commit.  The rest of the lines contain the remaining metadata, including the name of the person who made the commit, and the log message.

Because this stuff is in a commit, it's all committed.  There aren't any *changes* either: the `tree` listed here holds a complete snapshot of *all* the files.  We can view the tree directly, again using `git cat-file -p`, but it's long and kind of boring:

```
100644 blob 12a89f95f993546888410613458c9385b16f0108    .clang-format
100644 blob 1bdc91e282c5393c527b3902a208227c19971b84    .gitattributes
[snippage]
100644 blob 536e55524db72bd2acf175208aef4f3dfc148d42    COPYING
040000 tree 814822a9a0a75e17294704b37950c30361401a85    Documentation
[lots more snippage]
100644 blob ec6e574e4aa07414b9a17bb99ddee26fd44497de    xdiff-interface.c
100644 blob 135fc05d72e8f066a63902785d12485a656efa97    xdiff-interface.h
040000 tree 12edaa3d770f84e31ee58826eea93ea6ca64d939    xdiff
100644 blob d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6    zlib.c
```

If we follow each of the sub-`tree` lines, we eventually collect up the entire snapshot for commit `1fd4a47af4942cbdee0bdcb4375612ab521a4a51` in the Git repository for Git.  Each `blob` line gets us the hash ID of a file that goes with that commit, while the *name* of the file is at the end of the line.  So this commit in Git has a version of `zlib.c` that has hash ID `d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6`, and we can view that file as well with `git cat-file -p` if we want:

```
$ git cat-file -p d594cba3fc9d82d94b9277e886f2bee265e552f6 | head
/*
 * zlib wrappers to make sure we don't silently miss errors
 * at init time.
 */
#include "cache.h"
[rest snipped]
```

#### These are all frozen / read-only

Everything stored in the main repository body, under these hash ID keys, is completely, entirely, 100% read-only.  The reason for this is simple: the hash ID key is actually a cryptographic checksum of the data!  (Well, of the data plus a very small header giving the object's type and size.)  When you give Git a hash ID as a key, and Git uses that to extract the object from the repository database, Git does a consistency check: it re-checksums the retrieved data to make sure it matches the hash ID it used in the first place.  These two *must* match: if they don't, Git knows that the object has become corrupted somehow, e.g., due to disk failure, or something along those lines.

#### Names find tip commits; commits find their parents, to make a backwards chain

As we noted above, a name like `master` contains the commit hash ID of the *tip* commit of that branch.  If we use the hash ID to retrieve the commit itself, we get a `parent` line.  The parent tells us the hash ID of the commit that *was* the tip of the branch, at some earlier time.  We say that each of these things—the branch name, and the commit itself—*points to* a commit, and we can draw these pointers as arrows:

```
... <-parent  <-tip   <--master
```

Git can start at the tip commit, and do something with that commit.  Then Git can use the parent ID to find the previous commit, and do something with it.  The parent is its own parent, and Git can look at that commit, and so on.  Eventually the entire chain leads back to a point where the action stops, typically at the very first commit ever made.  If there are two branch names, with different commits at their branch tips, in a pretty small repository, we can draw out the entire thing like this:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
       \
        E--F--G   <-- develop
```

The internal linkages always point backwards, from commit to parent.  Since the objects themselves are read-only, no commit remembers its children: those are created too late.  But all children always remember all of their parents.  When we make a *merge commit*, such as merging `G` into `D`, the merge remembers *both* of its parents:

```
A--B--C--D------H   <-- master
       \       /
        E--F--G   <-- develop
```

and the same thing happens as always happens whenever we make a new commit: the *current branch name* changes, so that `master` points to `H` instead of `D`.  The *first* parent of a merge commit, and the only (and thus first) parent of an ordinary non-merge commit, is the commit that *was* the tip just a moment ago.

To put it another way: **Branch names move; commits stay put.**

#### Everything committed is in a special, Git-only format

The *blob* objects, the things that contain the files, that we saw above, identified by hash ID, are in a special, Git-only, compressed format.  (The commits and trees are also compressed, though this is less important, since only Git really uses those directly.)  This is no good for our own use, though, so we need a place where Git can extract files into their ordinary uncompressed format.  These files also need to be *changeable*, and the Git-only frozen blob objects are not.

Hence, each repository generally comes with one (1) *work-tree*, into which Git extracts and decompressses committed files.  The initial contents of the work-tree come out of one of the frozen commits.

Git does, of course, need a way to make *new* commits.  There is a similar version control system (Mercurial) that makes new commits using the work-tree, and Git could have done that, but Git does not do that.  Git has, instead, this thing called, variously, the *index*, or the *staging area*, or the *cache*.  The role of the index can get fairly complicated—Git expands it quite a lot during conflicted merge operations, for instance—but it's perhaps best described as *the place you build up the next commit you will make*.  This is its role as *staging area*.

New commits are complete snapshots, not just changes!  So the index / staging-area holds *all the files from the current commit*.  Git simply copies the current commit *to* the index, which makes the index contain all the files.  The files in the index are still in the special Git-only format, but—this is the crucial difference from the committed copies—they are now *writable*.

#### We can now observe the process of checking out a commit and making a new commit

Let's start with a six-commit repository.  In this repository, let's add the *remote-tracking* names (`origin/*`) as well, and attach the name `HEAD` to `master`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master (HEAD), origin/master
       \
        E--F   <-- origin/develop
```

Now let us do this:

```
$ git checkout develop
```

(and let's assume that the repository has just been cloned and has everything "clean").  The branch name `develop` does not exist yet!  Rather than failing, `git checkout` actually *creates* it right now using `origin/develop` as the hash ID, so that the name `develop` springs into being, pointing to commit `F`.

The next step can be quite complicated (see [Checkout another branch when there are uncommitted changes on the current branch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22053757/1256452)) but we're assuming everything is clean, and we can therefore simplify it further: Git takes the contents of the tree in `F`, puts that into the index, and makes the work-tree match by removing any files that were in it that shouldn't be, and making all the other files match those in the index, but de-compressed.  Git attaches the name `HEAD` to `develop`.  Our commit-graph drawing is unchanged, except for where `HEAD` is attached to the new *name* `develop`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        E--F   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

We can now happily modify files in the work-tree.  After we are done with that, we run `git add` on whichever ones we changed.  This copies the work-tree files into the index, compressing them and making them ready for committing:

```
$ [edit various files]
$ git add -u             # or -A or `.` or list the files or whatever
```

Now that the index matches the work-tree, we run:

```
$ git commit             # with -m to avoid using the editor, or whatever
```

Git packages up the index's contents (as a tree with subtrees as appropriate), freezing all the pre-compressed files into a new tree, and makes a new commit.  The new commit's parent is `F`, because `HEAD` is attached to `develop` and `develop` contains `F`'s hash ID.  The new commit's tree is the tree Git just packaged up, the author is "us", and so on.  Writing out the commit produces a new, unique hash ID for our new commit `G`.  Git writes that hash ID into the name `develop`, and now we have:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        E--F--G   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
```

and our index and work-tree match each other and match commit `G`, since `G` was just made *from* our index.

#### All other items build from here

In an edit or comment, you mentioned using `git stash`.  What `git stash` does is to make *commits*.  The thing that is special about the commits that `git stash` makes is that they are on *no* branch.

It actually makes at least two commits, one for the current index content, and one for the work-tree content, in case you have staged (with `git add`) some stuff and not-staged (by not adding) more stuff.  Both of these commits are full snapshots!  I like to draw them as `i` and `w`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master, origin/master
       \
        E--F--G   <-- develop (HEAD), origin/develop
              |\
              i-w   <-- refs/stash
```

Git finds the `w` commit through the special name `refs/stash` (which is not a branch name—branches are in `refs/heads/`, e.g., `refs/heads/master` and `refs/heads/develop`).  The `w` commit finds the `i` commit, and also the commit on which the stash was made (`G`); the `i` commit also links back to the commit that was current when you made the stash.

Having made the two (normal stash) or three (`--include-untracked` or `--all`) stash commits, `git stash` runs `git reset --hard` to clean out the index and work-tree, making them match the current commit.  There are more options here as well, but that covers the basic operation of `git stash`.

#### `git worktree add`, and other special cases

Using `git worktree`, we can create new, additional work-trees that go with the current repository.  Each added work-tree has its own index.  The index for each work-tree caches (hence the name *cache*) a lot of data *about* that work-tree, and Git uses that to quickly scan through, or even avoid scanning, the work-tree: this is how and why the index *indexes* the work-tree, hence the name *index*.

Besides all of these, you can create your own temporary index files!  This is how `git stash` works, for instance.  First it makes a mostly-ordinary commit `i` of the *current* index, which is easy since Git already knows how to do that, but then it has to commit the work-tree.  Git can only build new commits from an index, so what `git stash` does is to create a *temporary* index, stuff all the work-tree files into it, and use that to make the `w` commit.

A number of other fancy Git tricks can make use of temporary or alternate index files.  One must use care with these, since Git in general assumes that *the* index indexes / caches *the* work-tree—or that the added, per-work-tree index caches that particular added work-tree—and if you get things out of sync, some interestingly subtle failures occur.

Comment: this is a great answer, I will have to read it a few times to absorb it all..I am not sure if you addressed the git-stash thing though. All I know is that you can't switch from your current branch unless you commit the changes or use --force. If you use --force your changes are lost. But if you use stash, you can stash your changes. So what I am saying is the only branch that can have a dirty index is the current branch, unless there are some stashed changes? It looks like there is only one git stash, not a different stash for each branch, which makes sense given what you mentioned.

Comment: @AlexanderMills: `git stash` makes two commits (hence saving snapshots). Then it runs `git reset --hard HEAD`, so that your index and work-tree match the current commit. That's what allows you to switch to another branch, if you could not earlier: the index and work-tree are now clean (match the current commit) because of the `git reset --hard`, which replaced your files with those from the current commit. It is the two `git stash` commits—on *no* branch—that save the changed files (and all other *unchanged* files as well!).

Comment: thanks, one question I have - can you apply git stash commits to any branch, or just the branch that you were on when you called git stash? I am guessing the former, but not 100% sure.

Comment: You can attempt the apply anywhere. It's *guaranteed to work* if you have, as the current commit, the same commit you made when you made the stash. Otherwise it may have merge conflicts (`git stash apply` uses Git's internal merge machinery to do the application).

Answer (score 1):

The work tree and the index are not specific to any branch. Having "unstaged" or "uncommited" changes is therefore not a property of a branch that you can query directly.

However, you can compare the work tree to a particular branch:

```
git diff <branch name>
```

Or to compare the index to a particular branch,

```
git diff --cached <branch name>
```

In both cases, omitting the `<branch name>` basically defaults to the currently checked out branch.

Comment: what's the difference between the worktree and the index?

Comment: nvm, this explained it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git