# Does Git index have similar purpose of database index?

Tags: database, git, indexing

A Git repository can be viewed as a database.

Does Git index have similar purpose of database index, given they are both named "index"?  (I can't figure out any relation between them, but I don't know much.)

Comment: They have no relation in any way AFAIK.  The Git index is a logical place where certain files (and their underlying blobs and plumbing) are placed before a new commit is made in a Git branch.  A database index is an ordered data structure, usually a B-tree, which represents a portion of data in a table in a certain order.  So, not much in common here.

Comment: I've never liked the word "index" for the Git index. It's a staging area, and nothing like any of the senses of the word "index" I can find in a dictionary or elsewhere in computer science.

Comment: what is the most accurate computer science and system term to name git index?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between HEAD, working tree and index, in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git)

Comment: As @joanis said, "index" is a poor choice of name for this Git-specific data structure. *Staging area* and *cache* are better names, but still not great as Git's index has aspects of both. Git could perhaps call it "the Git mishmash" and be less confusing. :-)

Comment: @Tim: I'd vote for "staging area" as the best term.

Comment: I just realized, there is a sense in which the Git index is indeed an index: the index data structure is basically a list of file-names and the staged blobs for those files. So it is the index for the current staging area, thus not so poorly named after all.

Answer (score 1):

The 'commit hash' in Git has a closer relation to an 'index' in database terminology.

An 'index' in Git has a totally different meaning. An index is the differences between the last commit and the changes you've 'staged' for the next commit.