# GitLab: Difference between "git diff < file-name >" and "git diff FETCH_HEAD -- < file-name >" for comparing local files to the remote repository

Tags: git, gitlab

Say I have a remote repository with a branch called 'development', and I am currently within this development branch.

What is the functional difference between using `git diff <file-name>`

**vs**

first using `git fetch origin development` and then using `git diff FETCH_HEAD -- <file-name>` ?

This is with the goal of comparing my local edited code to what's on the remote development branch repository.

I've tried both ways and they seem to result in the same comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Let's say I have a clone of a remote repository:

```
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/hello.git
```

And that I've recently fetched changes like this:

```
cd hello
git fetch origin master
```

Inside my work tree, I modify a file:

```
sed -i s/GNU/MOO/g README
```

At this point, both `git diff README` and `git diff FETCH_HEAD -- README` will show the same content, because the file in my local repository and the remote repository are identical. But let's say I stage the change to be committed:

```
git add README
```

Now, running `git diff README` will return nothing, because `git diff` compares the work tree to the index (and running `git add README` added the modified version of `README` to the index)...but `git diff FETCH_HEAD -- README` still returns a difference, because while my local files matches what's in my index, it differs from what is stored in (our local cache of) the remote repository.

---

(It's important to note here that we're never actually comparing anything against the remote repository: the only commands that interact directly with a remote are things like `fetch`, `pull`, and `push`. Everything else is interacting with *local* data that reflects what the remote looked like last time we ran `git fetch`; any changes that occurred in the remote repository since that point will be unknown to us until we next update our local cache.)

---

Address your questions in the comments:

> What is meant by the "index" and how does that differ from what is in the remote?

The git index is described in [the git community book](https://shafiul.github.io/gitbook/1_the_git_index.html). It is effectively the staging area that holds thing you `git add` before they are committed to the local repository.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3689838/whats-the-difference-between-head-working-tree-and-index-in-git),

> In this scenario you give, if I always follow up my "git add" with a "git commit and git push", then wouldn't redoing the "git fetch" method I mentioned result in the same output, i.e. no differences?

Sure. If you follow `git push` with `git fetch`, then your local
repository will reflect the state of the remote repository (it's
always possible that someone else will make changes between your `git push` and `git fetch`, so it's *possible* you would see differences,
but it's unlikely).

> Is it then okay that, assuming I am always committing after using git add, to treat git diff  as equivalent? I.e. as a way to check my changes against the remote?

Not generally, no. `git diff` shows you how a file differs from your
*local* repository, If you want to compare your changes to a remote
branch, then ensure your local cache is up-to-date (`git fetch origin master`, or maybe `git remote update`), and then diff against the
appropriate remote branch (`git diff FETCH_HEAD` or `git diff origin/master`, etc).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer it is very helpful. What is meant by the "index" and how does that differ from what is in the remote? In this scenario you give, if I always follow up my "git add" with a "git commit and git push", then wouldn't redoing the "git fetch" method I mentioned result in the same output, i.e. no differences? Is it then okay that, assuming I am always committing after using git add, to treat git diff <file-name> as equivalent? I.e. as a way to check my changes against the remote?

Comment: I've updated the answer in response to your comments.

Comment: You can get the appropriate remote branch using `@{u}`

Comment: ...if you have set an upstream for your current branch (which you will have by default if you have checked out a copy of a remote branch).

Comment: Hi thank you for the follow-up! Just to check my understanding: Generally in my workflow I always follow up my git commits to the local repository with a git push to the remote repository, and only one person is pushing to a given branch at a time (each analyst has their own branch), thus my local and remote repositories are always in sync, and so the distinction between using 'git diff' and 'git fetch' is irrelevant. Am I correct in my thinking?