# Is using git staging/index for checkpointing no longer working?

Tags: git

In a relatively popular, but admittedly old (2008), post called My Git Workflow from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690796/1231693), I see:

> Added: This way I can checkpoint every few minutes. It’s a very cheap
> operation, and I don’t have to spend time cleaning up the checkpoints
> later. “git diff” tells me what I’ve changed since the last
> checkpoint; “git diff head” shows what’s changed since the last
> commit. “git checkout .” reverts to the last checkpoint; “git checkout
> head .” reverts to the last commit. And “git stash” and “git checkout
> -m -b” operate on the changes since the last commit, which is what I want.

But when I try those commands:

```bash
git add -A
git checkout head .  # Updated 1 path from 764c16d
git checkout .       # Updated 0 paths from the index
```

I seem to "lose" my change! How do I get my changes back?

This doesn't work:

```bash
git checkout 764c16d  # fatal: Cannot switch branch to a non-commit '764c16d'
git reset 764c16d     # error: object 764c16d... is a tree, not a commit
```

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your basic overall question: Nothing relevant about Git has changed in general since 2008.

Basically you've combined two totally different sets of instructions and are expecting them to work together by magic. They don't, and they were never intended to. No one ever suggested that you say `git add -A` and then say `git checkout ...`. It was always, is always, and probably will always be the case that `git checkout ...` overwrites both the index and the working tree — because that is what `checkout` *means*. If you don't want that to happen, don't do that.

So what *does* the author of that post mean? Well, far be it from me to try to explain someone else's writing (I can barely explain my own writing, and there's plenty of it going around). But I think the post is saying that if you decide you *don't like* the current situation and you *want* to throw away your work, you use `git checkout`.

Finally, in answer to your last-posed question "How do I get my changes back?" You don't. You can switch back to a diffferent commit after a `git checkout` just by saying `git switch -` to take you back to the branch you were on previously. But what you wrote into the index is gone forever.

Basically, `git checkout` is one of Git's "dangerous" command, and you really shouldn't use it at all any more; this is exactly why `git switch` and `git restore` were created, so that you know what's going to happen and can't so easily wipe out a bunch of stuff by mistake. The creation of those commands is something that *has* changed since 2008!

Comment: This is the grumpiest yet most entertaining response I've seen on SO for a while. Thanks for the clear answer and for making me smile.

Comment: Thanks! If there were a "grumpy but entertaining" gold badge I would totally have it!!!