# Visual Studio 2022. Git Track changes feedback on left margin only appears if file is not staged

Tags: git, version-control, visual-studio-2022, text-editor, git-stage

I have a file Staged, the text editor track changes margin is not appearing:
[image]

But if I unstage it, these track changes marks will appear on the margin:
[image]

Is there any way I can change it to always show the changes on the margin, even if the file is staged?

Answer (score 0):

There does not appear to be a way to do this.  I have a feeling its due more to how `git add` and/or `git diff` works than it is a Visual Studio problem.  Visual Studio Code exhibits the same behavior as well.

I *think* it is because when you stage an item, it is no longer within your working directory, but rather now in the staging area (or index). I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3690522/6530134) which lead me to the book *Pro Git*.  In this book, for `git diff` (see the Git Basics chapter), it states the following:

> It’s important to note that git diff by itself doesn’t show all changes made since your last commit — only changes that are still unstaged. If you’ve staged all of your changes, git diff will give you no output.

This goes back to when I said it might be due to have `git add` and `git diff` works.  Visual Studio is essentially doing a `git diff` to determine the modified lines in your file.  And since the lines of code in question are now staged (`git add`'ed), `git diff` can no longer display the changes.

Comment: I don't know what Visual Studio is doing behind the scenes, as I came from the Subversion and TFS world and I am relatively new to Git. But I can go to a **Staged** file and click on the menu `Git > Compare with unmodified` where I will see the Visual Studio compare tool doing its job. If there is a way to do this on staged files, I presume there also must be a way to mark the track changes on the margin of the text editor for staged files.