# Do all diffs get copied to source branch from destination branch during git merge?

Tags: git, version-control, merge

I have been trying to get all the diffs from a dst branch to a src branch. I usually follow the following workflow.

```
git checkout dst (switch to dst branch)
git pull dst     (fetch and merge changes on remote dst to local dst)
git checkout src (switch to src branch)
git merge dst    (pull all diffs from dst to src?)
[optionally if merge conflicts occur, I resolve merge conflicts and do]
git commit
```

However, after merge, I am seeing that not all diffs are copied to my src branch. For instance  `git diff src:somefile dst:somefile` shows additions in `somefile` between the src and dst, however these changes are **not** copied over to src which I am expecting to happen after merge.

Is there something fundamentally wrong in the way I am thinking about merge? How do I get all the diffs (additions and deletions) from dst to src branch.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686452/what-are-the-differences-between-these-git-diff-commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there something fundamentally wrong in the way I am thinking about merge?

Yes:

> ... `git diff src:somefile dst:somefile` ...

This isn't what merge *does*.  Merging a branch does not mean "make my files the same as theirs".

#### The commit graph

Let's start with a bit of commit-graph drawing:

```
... <- B <- C <- D   <-- branch
```

Here, the uppercase letters stand in for a commit ID, i.e., one of those big ugly 40-character SHA-1 IDs like `f931ca0...`.  Each commit records a source tree (this is how, for instance, you can use `<id>:path` to see that file's contents as of that commit ID).  It also records some parent commit ID(s): usually just one ID, but sometimes more than one (a "merge" commit) and rarely zero parent IDs (a "root" commit).

The `branch` is just the name of one of your branches, and it contains commit-ID `D`, i.e., the branch name "points to" the tip-most commit `D` on that branch.  Commit `D` points back to `C`, which points back to `B`, and so on.

A graph becomes "branch-y" or "branched"—this term unfortunately collides with the same term we use to talk about the *name* of a branch—when several different commits point to the same parent.  Remember that the arrows here all point left-ish, even if they point up-and-left or down-and-left; and since text-style graphs don't have room for arrows, we'll just draw a line like `-` or `\` or `/` here:

```
... B - C - D   <-- br1
      \
        E - F   <-- br2
```

Here the tip of branch `br1` is commit `D`, and the tip of branch `br2` is commit `F`.  You can ask git for the actual ID, the concrete 40-character thing, using `git rev-parse`:

```
$ git rev-parse br1
e59f6c2d348d465e3147b11098126d3965686098
```

for instance.  Again, we say that `br1` "points to" commit `D`, which points back to `C`, which points back to `B`, and so on.  Meanwhile `br2` points to `F` which points to `E` which points back to `B`.

The commit that any given branch-name points to is the "tip commit" of that branch.  When you add a new commit to a branch, git does this by making the new commit store the previous tip's ID as its parent ID, and once the new commit is finalized and safely in the repository, changing the ID stored in the branch-name.  That is, if you add a new commit to `br1`, the new commit `G` will point back to `D`, and git will make `br1` point to `G`:

```
... B - C - D - G  <-- br1
      \
        E - F   <-- br2
```

No matter how many new tip commits we make over time, commit `B` remains especially interesting.  In graph theory terms, the concept here is "reachability": commit `B` is (always) reachable from *both* branch-tips.

#### Merge

So, here's what `git merge` does.  You give it two branch tip IDs—one of these is the branch you're on now, the other is the one you name—and it:

1. identifies the nearest commit reachable from both branch tips (this is the "merge base");
2. does a diff from the merge-base to the current-branch tip;
3. does a diff from the merge-base to the other tip;
4. combines these two diffs to see where "both sides" made the *same* changes;
5. applies the changes found in step 3, without re-applying the combined changes found in step 4; and
6. if all goes well, makes a new commit with *two* parents, those two parents being both branch-tips.

Conflicts occur wherever the changes found in steps 2 and 3 affect the same region of the same file, but are not *exactly* the same (hence can't be subtracted away via step 4).  If conflicts occur, git makes you resolve them; when you do your final `git commit` this still makes the same kind of "merge commit".

Now, suppose that somewhere along the way in the `B`-`C`-`D`-`G` line, someone modified the path `README.txt` to include an exclamation point in the first line.  Meanwhile in `B`-`E`-`F` line, nobody did this to `README.txt`.  The final merge commit will retain the change made here, but if you compare `br1:README` to `br2:README` there will be differences: the first line in `br2` won't have the exclamation point.  That's because the changes being merged-in (base-to-`br2`) don't change this; the changes being retained (base-to-`br1`) do.  We don't want base-to-`br1` changes to get *removed*, we only want changes that aren't already present (have not been made on "both side") to be *added*.

In any case, let's draw in the final merge commit `H`:

```
... B - C - D - G - H  <-- br1
      \           /
        E ----- F      <-- br2
```

Now `br1:README` has the `!` but `br2:README` doesn't.

In short, there's no reason to expect, after a merge, any two files to match in the new branch-tips.  If all the files had to match exactly, you'd wipe out all the work on `br1`, replacing it with only the work on `br2`.