# What is the difference between the commands 'git diff --staged' and 'git diff --cached'

Tags: git

I have just started learning git. I have a confusion between the commands `git diff --staged` and `git diff --cached`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the differences between these git diff commands?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3686452/what-are-the-differences-between-these-git-diff-commands)

Comment: Start with [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book).

Comment: If you wonder about a specific command like this, your first step should be to check the help for that command. Type `git diff --help` and then search for the specific arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In old versions of git, the staging area was referred to as cache/stage area. Today it's being called index.

From the docs:

> **`--staged`** is a synonym of **`--cached`**.

Stage/cache/index are all synonyms for the staging area. It simply depends on the git version you use. It was changed to index along the way (and today it's called index), but there are still a few commands which use `--cached`, like `git diff`, `git rm --cached`, etc.

[image: Git Workflow]

Comment: Thanks. I was confused what actually index is. You helped me out! :)

Comment: Added image so you can have a better picture what is this, its called the 3-states

Comment: Could I follow you somewhere?

Comment: Sure. i have posted you a FB git group which i manage, [https://www.facebook.com/groups/git.dvcs/]

Comment: Here are some cool answers which you can learn form a lot of stuff. simply click on my profile and read answer which i gave. like this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519665/how-to-move-head-back-to-a-previous-location-detached-head/34519716#34519716

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference between these two. From [`git diff` docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

> `--staged` is a synonym of `--cached`.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I am currently just rote learning the commands. Could you recommend me something that I could understand stuff? Thanks.

Comment: Here is a good place to star with: git scm, [https://www.facebook.com/groups/git.dvcs/] , [https://www.atlassian.com/git/]

Comment: [Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) is what you should start with.